# vscode: Is there any way to send keys to the task output console

Tags: task, visual-studio-code

I use task.json to run compile and simulation on a server through ssh.
In some situation, I have to interrupt the server running task by sending "ctrl+c".
But the task console seems like not supporting this feature.
Is there any method I missed?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to terminate a task in vscode you can use `Tasks: Terminate Running Task` command. To terminate a task via keyboard shortcut you can set a keyboard shortcut in keybindings.json to `workbench.action.tasks.terminate`.

Another way is to start your task via [Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) where Ctrl+C is supported.

Comment: What I want to terminate is the task running on my linux server launched with task.json. not vscode task itself.

Comment: @CharlesChen Have you tried the Integrated Terminal to start and terminate your server side tasks?

Comment: Yes. integrated terminal can do this, but no hotkey can help me to send a specific run command into the integrated terminal. I can just run with "F5" using task.json and the error/warning will be parsed with pre-designed regex.

Comment: Obligatory link to question on how to start tasks via integrated terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52097000/run-tasks-in-integrated-terminal-in-vscode