# Run tasks in Integrated Terminal in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, task

when I ran tasks (tasks.json) in the past, they ran inside the Integrated Terminal in VSCode. However, after resetting my dev machine and reinstalling everything, my tasks now run in a new cmd window. This is a problem when the task fails with an error. In this case, the cmd window is just closed and I can't read what the actual error is.

How do I get the tasks to run in the Integrated Terminal again?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using task.json with version 2

you just need write `presentation` property in `tasks` like below:

```
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": true,
            "panel": "shared",
            "showReuseMessage": true,
            "clear": false
        }
```

full example like below

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "example",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "foo",
        "args": [],
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": true,
            "panel": "shared",
            "showReuseMessage": true,
            "clear": false
        }
    }
]
```

for more information you can read [vscode task.json help](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)